# Write file without php

Tags: javascript, html

I work on a JS/HTML website, I would like to write in myFile.txt a string coming from a form, but I can't use php and myFile.txt is on the server side. 
I tried with JS but it's not done for...
I know that I must use a server-side language but I don't know how.

Comment: You cannot do with out server side languages..

Comment: You definitely need a server side language, whether that is PHP, node.js, ASP.NET, CGI, or anything else does not matter

Comment: Ok ! So, I don't know anyone of your solutions... Wich one I'd better use, and how can I be sure that my server can use it ?

Comment: impossible to say which is "best", as that depends on a host of factors, not the least of which is what your customer is already using. Given that you don't know any serverside systems, you would best tell the customer you're incapable of doing the job and hand it over to someone who can.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot interact with the server through client-side technologies (JavaScript, HTML, CSS).  The only way to accomplish this is with a server-side language (such as PHP, C#, Python, etc.).